# How to cusomize search in datatables with server-side processing on Laravel

Tags: php, laravel, datatables

Here's my code. JS:

```
var oTable = $('#tasktable').DataTable({
  serverSide: true,
  ajax: '{!! route('datatables.tasks') !!}',
  columns: [
    { data: 'id', name: 'id' },
    { data: 'date', name: 'date' },
    { data: 'task', name: 'task' },
    { data: 'mark', name: 'mark' },
    { data: 'user', name: 'user' },                        
  ],
})
```

PHP:

```
public function tasksData(Request $request)
{
  $result = Datatables::of(Tasks::query())->make(true);     
  return $result;
}
```

In datatbase in `mark` column I've stored html entities. Something like this:

```
<p>Lorem impsum&nbsp; dolor &nbsp; </p><a href="http://mail.com" class="mail">sit amet</a>
```

So when I try to search now, script work with all data. E.g. now it can find "mail.com". And I want to search text without tags contain, need to find only "Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet". How can I configure it?